# Unicode Printing in Java- abstract characters

Tags: java, unicode, printing

I'm making this program that prints Unicode characters. It looks something like this:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println('\u00A5');
        System.out.println((char) 0x00A5);
        System.out.println((char) (Integer.parseInt("00A5", 16)));
        System.out.println('\u261E');
        System.out.println((char) 0x261E);
        System.out.println((char) (Integer.parseInt("261E", 16)));
    }
}
```

The output looks like:

```
¥
¥
¥
?
?
?
```

Why does the latter half print question marks?

I can understand the program printing a Japanese character, but when I change it to [`\u261E`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/261e/index.htm), I can't recognize it. Any help?

Comment: for me it is working ¥
¥
¥
☞
☞
☞

Comment: I'm using Intellij- what IDE are you using?

Comment: Hmmm. Do you know how I can fix my IDE? I don't really know what's going on...

Comment: How do I check with JDK 8?

Comment: I got ¥ ¥ ¥ ☞ ☞ ☞, Eclipse Java8

Comment: Doesn't work in command prompt either... I think something is wrong with my Java but i have no clue what it could be.

Comment: add jdk8 in IDE by GO to file || project structure || project SDK || change your version to jdk8

Comment: It says my SDK version is 1.8.0_60 (I think thats the latest)- and my project level language is SDK default 8

Comment: ok i have spent time and check with jdk6 ,jdk7 also it is working as expected. i dont think it is the problem of java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the changes specific to your project then:

> Go to your project properties -> change `Text file encoding` to `UTF-8`

[image: This is for project specific changes]

`OR`

if you want to apply it to all projects globally then:

> got to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding

[image: this is for global changes]

**Note:**

> If you are using some other IDE, you should have similar option there too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think he posted sooner so I have him the gold (both had the same answer)

Comment: I have project specific answer too because we might not need to same encoding for all projects. Anyways you can upvote my efforts if not accept

Comment: I guess the visuals are a plus :)

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. This is an UTF-8 encoding. So you have to set encoding style as "UTF-8" in eclipse.
Change it Here :

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding

Comment: Thanks! Works great now.